# Java FileHandler disable log rotation

Tags: java, logging, filehandler

I am trying to disable log rotation, for file handler using,

```
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler
    ( "path" + "run.log", 1000000, 1, false);
```

What i want is one log, created for each run i do not want rotation or backing up of the old file, but using this initialization i get run.log run.log.1 run.log.2 for each run.

Also

```
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```

is set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `0` as the limit instead of `1000000`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`FileHandler fh = new FileHandler( "path" + "run.log", 1000000, 1, true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler fileHandler = new FileHandler(FILE_PATH, true);
```