# Java Log File creates multiple copies

Tags: java, swing, file, logging, filehandler

I am trying to create a logs file in a Java swings application that will contain all the messages generated by the code. But unfortunately it does not create 1 single log file but creates a structure as shown. I need 1 single log file.

[image]

My code:

```
 //get the logger object
logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");

try {
    // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter
    loggerFH = new FileHandler(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\resources\\logs\\logs.txt",true);
    logger.addHandler(loggerFH);            

    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    loggerFH.setFormatter(formatter);

} catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
    logger.severe(ex.getMessage());
    outputArea.append(ex.getMessage());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my Logger file was used by several instances at a time. So when 1 instance of filehandler locked the access to the file a new file was getting created. So I created a Synchronized class to handle all logging. And it worked great.

```
public class SynchronizedLogger {

//Logger to put error logs and messages in the log file

public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");


//Logger Filehandler
private static FileHandler loggerFH;

public SynchronizedLogger() {
}

public static synchronized void writeLog(String message) {
    logger.info(message);
}

public SynchronizedLogger(int i) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            // This block configures the logger with handler and formatter
            loggerFH = new FileHandler(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\resources\\logs\\logs.txt", 0, 1, true);
            logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
            logger.addHandler(loggerFH);

            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            loggerFH.setFormatter(formatter);
        }

    } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
        writeLog(ex.getMessage());
        outputArea.append("\n\n" + ex.getMessage());

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your files are being rotated.

Did you try solution from this:
[Java FileHandler disable log rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914457/java-filehandler-disable-log-rotation?rq=1)

FileHandler fh = new FileHandler( "path" , 0, 1, false);